# COMO ENVIAR VALORES ALMACENADOS EN VARIABLES A UN SERVIDOR UTILIZANDO POR RETROFIT, ANDROID STUDIO

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit

Estoy usando el `GPS` en mi aplicación para obtener la localización exacta del dispositivo al momento de un `OnClickListener`. Cuando se ejecuta mi clase las coordenadas de latitud y longitud obtenidas se almacenan en variables de tipo `double`, luego empleando `Geocoder` obtengo la ubicación de la calle y la almaceno en un `String`. Llegado a este punto, me gustaría saber de que manera puedo enviar esos valores almacenados a mi servidor por medio de `Retrofit`. Algún ejemplo de como hacerlo?

Comment: Hola David, te sugiero modificar tu pregunta en base a [ask], además responder a los comentarios de tus preguntas, ¿Alguna de las respuestas que te han dado los usuarios te han sido de utilidad?

Comment: si de hecho he puntuado las respuestas que me han sido de utilidad pero no las he respondido, soy nuevo aca, tratare de comentarlas cuando sean las correctas, o las que me funcionaron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo que estás solicitando es muy complejo de explicar pues depende de varios factores pero puedo orientarte un poco sobre lo que debes de investigar para dar solución a tu problema

Lo que intentas hacer necesita de un API en el servidor que pueda recibir los datos y procesarlos, puedes programar tu propio API en tu servidor, puedes usar el lenguaje de programación que quieras de acuerdo a tus conocimientos, estos son algunos frameworks que podrías utilizar:

- Laravel con PHP https://laravel.com/
- Express con NodeJS https://expressjs.com/es/
- Flask con Python https://flask.pocoo.org/

Son solo ejemplos, puedes usar cualquier otro que encuentres o te acomode.
Aprendiendo todo sobre las API REST Full podrás lograr lo que buscas, en tu app solo tendrías que enviar los datos mediante POST a tu endpoint que maneja la ubicación y listo, igual puedes encontrar muchos ejemplos de como se hace esto https://square.github.io/retrofit/

=======

Para enviar info con Retrofit debes crear tu manejador de la conexión y luego una interface que mande los datos

1. Creas el manejador de Retrofit:
   package com.example.network;

   // Importas tus JSON parsers
   import com.google.gson.Gson;
   import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
   // Esto es opcional, recomiendo tener tus endpoints y demás cosas que uses en tu API como constantes
   import com.example.utils.constants.ApiConstants;

   import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

   // Herramientas de SquareUp para las conexciones
   import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
   import retrofit2.Retrofit;
   import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

   // Esta será tu clase que te generará un manejador de conexión cuando abras una nueva instancia de tu interfaz
   public class ServiceGenerator {
       // Esto creará tu conexión y le pasas algunas configuraciones
               // puedes ver que más puedes configurar en la web de SquareUp OkHTTP
       private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
         .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS).connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
         // Tu parser de JSON que usarás con Retrofit
       private static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
       // Tu instancia de Retrofit a la que le indicarás que manejador de conexión usarás y tu parser
       private static Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
         .baseUrl(ApiConstants.API_URL)
         .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson));
         // Tu instancia de retrofit como si fuera un singleton
       private static Retrofit retrofit;

   ```
   // este método te creará la interfaz para retrofit con la conexión lista
   public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
       if (retrofit == null) {
           OkHttpClient client = httpClient.build();
           retrofit = builder.client(client).build();
       }
       return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
   }
   ```

   }
2. Creas tu interfaz, nota: este ejemplo está en kotlin pero es fácil de entender como hacerlo en Java:
   package com.example.network

   import com.example.models.Location
   import com.example.models.responses.LocationsResponse
   import com.example.utils.constants.ApiConstants
   import retrofit2.Call
   import retrofit2.http.*

   interface ApiInterface {

   ```
   @POST(ApiConstants.API_VERSION + ApiConstants.LOCAtIONS)
   fun postLocations(@Body location_obj: Location): Call<LocationsResponse>
   ```

   }
3. Creas tu modelo para tus ubicaciones Location.java es el que se usa arriba, algo como:
   package com.example.models.Location;

   public class Location() {
       private Double lat;
       private Double lon;
       private String address;

   ```
   public construct(Double lat, Double lon, String address) {
       this.lat = lat;
       this.lon = lon;
       this.address = adress;
   }
   // acá tus get y set
   ```

   }
4. Lo mismo para tu respuesta del API, es el LocationsResponses.java de tu interfaz, basicamente es un objeto listo para recibir el payload de tu API
5. Por último en tu activity o fragment llamas al generador de servicio pasándole la clase de tu interfaz y sobre eso ejecutas las funciones de la interfaz pasándole el objeto Location con tus datos:
   package com.example;

   // importas todos los modelos que usarás
   import com.example.network.ServiceGenerator;
   import com.example.models.Location;
   import com.example.models.responses.LocationsResponse;

   // importas lo que usarás de retrofit
   import retrofit2.Call;
   import retrofit2.Callback;
   import retrofit2.Response;

   public class AppsFragment extends Fragment {
       ...
       ...
       // tu función que envía los datos a tu servidor
       // recibe un objeto Location así que primero lo creas con los datos que obtienes del gps y la dirección
       private void postNewLocation(Location location) {
           // acá creas tu interfaz con el generador de servicios del paso 1
           // le pasas la interface del paso 2
           ApiInterface api = ServiceGenerator.createService(ApiInterface.class);
           // ya con tu interface lista ejecutas la función postLocation que fue la que asignamos para esto
           // le pasas el objeto Location que es lo que espera recibir y lo que enviará mediante POST como payload
           // enqueue es para añadir a los procesos la llamada
           api.postLocation(Location).enqueue(new Callback() {
               // con esto esperas la respuesta de tu servidor para ver si todo salió bien
               // call es tu llamada original y response la respuesta del servidor
               @Override
               public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
                   // acá vendrá tu respuesta del API para que verifiques si todo salió bien
               }

   ```
           // esto captura los posibles problemas de conexzión
           // IMPORTANTE: esto solo se ejecuta si fué imposible la conexión con tu servidor
           // si el servidor responde con código 4xx o 5xx esto no lo captura
           @Override
           public void onFailure(Call<LocationsResponse> call, Throwable t) {
               // acá encontrarás los detalles de la excepción si algo falla, es la variable t
               t.printStackTrace();
           }
       })
   }
   ```

   }

Espero te sea de utilidad, igual en el enlace de Retrofit hay más información

Comment: Si es que se que debo crear el API en el servidor, lo que queria saber es mas o menos como era la estructura de como se enviaban los valores almacenados o en este caso el contenido de mis variables.

Comment: @David Villegas acá te dejo la explicación de como usar Retrofit2

Comment: Esta muy bien explicado, ya tengo lo demas creado, ya que estoy enviando y recibiendo datos por otros metodos, necesitaria mi constructor y enviarlo, la cosa era por que no queria enviar un valor especifico o constante como una letra o numero arbitrario, sino valores variables obtenidos a partir del gps :) , pero me aclaraste mas la duda.